# $P \mapsto f^{-1}(P) : \operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is a continuous map between Zariski topologies.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A, B$ be commutative rings with $1$.

Let $f: A \to B$ be a ring homomomorphism.  For $P \in \operatorname{Spec} B$, $f^{-1}(P) \in \operatorname{Spec} A$, so that $g : \operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ defined by $g(P) = f^{-1}(P)$ is a function.  The goal is to show that for any $V(I) \subset \operatorname{Spec} A$ a closed set, that $g^{-1}(V(I)) = V(f(I)B)$.  Since then $g^{-1}$ takes closed sets to closed sets and so is continuous.

So far I have:

$$
P \in g^{-1}(V(I)) \\ \iff g(P) = f^{-1}(P) \in V(I) \\ \iff ?
$$

I know that if $P \supset f(I)B$ then $P \supset f(I)$ since $P$ has to be a proper ideal.  Not sure where that plugs into the proof though.

Comment: You should use the definition of $V(I)$.

Comment: @Thorgott $V(I) = \{ A \supset \text{prime } Q \supset I \}$ so that $P = f(f^{-1}(P)) \in f(V(I))$, but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: It's not necessarily the case that $P=f(f^{-1}(P))$.

Comment: @Thorgott, so $S = f(f^{-1}(P)) \subset P$ is a subring and $SB \subset BP = P$ since $P$ is an ideal and absorbs all of $B$.

Comment: $S$ is never a subring. However, you also do not need that.

Comment: @Thorgott any hints?

Comment: You know $I\subseteq f^{-1}(P)$. Apply $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Thorgott for teaching me.

The step I was missing was if $I \subset f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ then $f(I) \subset ff^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) \subset \mathfrak{p}$.

Thus, we have:

$$
g^{-1}(V(I)) = \{ P \in \operatorname{Spec} B: g(P) \in V(I) \} \\
= \{ P \in \operatorname{Spec} B: f^{-1}(P) \in V(I) \} \\
= \{ P \in \operatorname{Spec} B: I \subset f^{-1}(P) \} \\
= \{ P \in \operatorname{Spec} B: f(I) \subset ff^{-1}(P) \subset P \} \\
= V(f(I)B) = V(IB)
$$

The last equality is just by notational definition of $IB \equiv f(I)B$ as used in Matsumura's text.  That's the extension of an ideal along $f$.  And $A \cap J \equiv f^{-1}(J)$ is the contraction of $J$ along $f$.  All just notational.

Comment: You also have to note, that, conversely, $f(I)\subset P$ implies $I\subset f^{-1}(P)$. Also, the last equality doesn't make sense to me. What's $IB$? $I$ is a subset of $A$, not $B$.

Comment: @Thorgott $IB \equiv f(I)B$ is just notational from Matsumura.  Correspondingly $f^{-1}(J) \equiv A \cap J$ is the contraction notation, while the first notation is the "extension" of an ideal along $f: A \to B$.